# Android Handler keeps running for a while even after the activity has been destroyed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sensors

I read that the `handler.postDelayed` method helps pause a task for any amount of time. So I wrote it into the light sensor so that the sensor only detects light every 2 seconds, in order to save battery life:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SensorManager sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    Sensor light = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);
    SensorEventListener listener;

    if (light != null) {

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sm.registerListener(listener, light, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
            }
        };

        listener = new SensorEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "accuracy changed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

                sm.unregisterListener(listener, light);

                // Do the stuff here with the received sensor light value, which is event.values[0]
                
                handler.postDelayed(task, 2000);
            }
        };

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        sm.unregisterListener(listener, light);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        sm.registerListener(listener, light, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        sm.unregisterListener(listener, light);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        sm.unregisterListener(listener, light);
    }
}
```

At first it seemed to work fine. But I found that every time I exit the app it kept detecting the light for like 20 to 30 seconds as if the activity was still open. What am I doing wrong? I even added both the onStop and onDestroy methods just to be sure it was closing correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the **onDestroy()** of your activity clear your handler like

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

And it will stop right away!

Comment: One sec as I try it

Comment: I think it worked :). But I still don't get it, what was the problem?

Comment: The Handler has no idea that the Activity has been destroyed and will execute the posted task any way and since that task re-register the listener, it will cause an endless loop and also a memory leak since the task and listener are anonymous classes which hold an implicit reference to the Activity.

Comment: @patrick.elmquist Hi I wanted to ask another question but don't want to post again. My question is: Does the method I'm using actually preserve battery? I'm not sure if the continuous registering and unregistering of the light sensor drains more power than just leaving it on.

Comment: The handler works on a separate thread. Your garbage collector may or may not destroy it upon your application getting killed. 
Also this should prevent any memory leaks.

Comment: I'll recommend using a coroutine if you're familiar with Kotlin. They are light weight and easy to use. You need to do this CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
delay(2000);
.... your code;
repeat(your number);
}

Comment: @User104163 I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Jaswant "The handler works on a separate thread" that's not accurate. If nothing else is specified in the construction of the Handlar it will run on the same thread where it's created, in this case the Main thread.